# How to detect NULL rows in PostgreSQL sum()

Tags: postgresql, null, sum, aggregate-functions

I want to aggregate the sum of a column, while tracking the presence of NULL values which signal an error condition. E.g., take the table numbers:

```
# select * from numbers;
  n   |  l  
------+-----
    1 | foo
    2 | foo
 NULL | bar
    4 | bar
```

Given a label `l`, I want to compute the sum of numbers `n` with that label, provided there are no `NULL` values. Ideally, for a label without any rows, the sum would be 0. So I'm looking for some query `q` such that
`q('foo') = 3`, `q('baz') = 0` and `q('bar')` somehow signals an error, e.g. by returning `NULL`.

I started with the `sum()` [aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html), but that converts `NULL` rows to 0. One solution would be a variant that returns `NULL` provided there are any `NULL` values.

`sum()` gives

```
# select sum(n) from numbers where l = 'bar';
 sum 
-----
   4
```

but I'd rather have `sumnull()` with

```
# select sumnull(n) from numbers where l = 'bar';
 sumnull 
---------
  NULL
```

The best solution I've found so far is to also count non-NULL rows and compare to the total count:

```
# select sum(n), count(*), count(n) as notnull from numbers;
 sum | count | notnull 
-----+-------+---------
   7 |     4 |       3
```

Then if `count` is unequal to `notnull`, I know the result is not valid.

Comment: I am not aware of any standard SQL function to do that. But you can easily create such an aggregate function.

Comment: Additionally to the answers below. Sometimes it could be more efficiency to split the task into the two steps: 1) check is the `null` value exists (using an index on the column) and if not 2) calculate the sum.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is an empty set good enough?

```
create table numbers (n int);
insert into numbers values (1),(2),(null),(4);

select sum(n)
from numbers
having bool_and(n is not null);
 sum 
-----
(0 rows)
```

If you really need a null value it is a bit more complex:

```
with sum_null as (
    select sum(n) as sum_n
    from numbers
    having bool_and(n is not null)
)
select case
    when not exists (select 1 from sum_null) then null
    else (select sum_n from sum_null) end
;
 sum_n 
-------

(1 row)
```

Replacing the `having` line for:

```
having not bool_or(n is null)
```

is less readable but potentially much faster since it can stop searching at the first `null` found.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE

Comment: You're right, an empty result set is actually a more useful result for signalling an error condition. One nitpick is that I would regard an empty table as fine and expect the sum 0, though clearly I didn't put that into the question. This can be solved by changing to `having coalesce(bool_and(n is not null), true)`.

Answer (score 8):

You can create a custom aggregate, e.g.:

```
create or replace function int_sum_null(int, int)
returns int language sql as $$
    select $1 + $2
$$;

create aggregate sumnull(integer) (
    sfunc = int_sum_null,
    stype = int
);

select sum(n), sumnull(n)
from numbers;

 sum | sumnull 
-----+---------
   7 | <null>      
(1 row)
```

---

**Update #1**

Solutions without a custom aggregate:

```
select case 
    when bool_or(n is null) then null 
    else sum(n) end
from numbers;

select coalesce((
    select sum(n)
    from numbers
    having not bool_or(n is null)), null);
```

These variants are based on the [Clodoaldo Neto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39704281/1995738) idea. If you like them please upvote his answer too.

---

**Update #2**

Modify the custom aggregate `sumnull` and add the initial condition:

```
drop aggregate sumnull(integer);
create aggregate sumnull(integer) (
    sfunc = int_sum_null,
    stype = int,
    initcond = 0
);
```

to get the results you have described in the updated question:

```
create table numbers (n int, l text);
insert into numbers values 
(1, 'foo'), (2, 'foo'), (null, 'bar'), (4, 'bar');

select 
    sumnull(n) filter (where l = 'foo') foo, 
    sumnull(n) filter (where l = 'bar') bar, 
    sumnull(n) filter (where l = 'baz') baz
from numbers;

 foo | bar | baz 
-----+-----+-----
   3 |     |   0
(1 row)
```

Comment: You could replace `int` with `anyelement`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe IMO not `anyelement` but `numeric`

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - yes, this is possible, however system aggregates are defined for individual types. There is a difference in error reporting when an aggregate is used improperly.

Comment: Worth noting is that the custom aggregate (`sumnull`) is incredibly slower than the built-in `sum` (in my case, about 10x). In case you're looking for performance, the case statement is a much better solution.

Answer (score 3):

1) Use [COALESCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL)

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(n,'NaN'::numeric)) FROM numbers;
```

If any row is NULL then result will be as 'NaN'

2) You will get NULL as result if any row has NULL value else result as number

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbers WHERE n IS NULL) > 0 THEN NULL
        ELSE (SELECT SUM(COALESCE(n, 0)) FROM numbers)
END
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have it return `NaN` for those cases by using `coalesce` to replace `NULL` with `NaN`;

```
create table t(
  val int
);

insert into t (val) values (1), (2), (NULL);
select sum(coalesce(val, double precision 'NaN')) from t;
```

Result: `NaN`.

```
insert into t (val) values (1), (2), (3);
select sum(coalesce(val, double precision 'NaN')) from t;
```

Result: `6`.

See this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3e04d/2)